# CSS translate to the top of <ul> with animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animations

What I'm trying to achieve is to translate an item in a `<UL>` to the top of the list but with a transition effect.
This is what I have till now:

```js
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
  $("#select").addClass("is-moved");
});
```

```css
.navbar-nav{
  margin 0;
 }

.nav{
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.singlechatContainer {
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -o-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
}
.is-moved {
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(calc(-20vw + 70px));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Test button</button>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="singlechatContainer ">Test</li>
    <li class="singlechatContainer ">Test</li>
    <li class="singlechatContainer ">Test</li>
   <li class="singlechatContainer ">Hello1</li>
   <li id="select" class="singlechatContainer ">Hello2</li>
   <li class="singlechatContainer ">Hello3</li>
<ul>
```

My problem is that I have to change the container position to absolute to be able to make the animation. But I don't know how to change this back and keep it as first item in the UL.

What I want to achieve looks like this, but with 'hello1' becoming the second item.:

[image]

another problem is that if you scroll while it's moving, it will move till the visual top of the list and won't continue (I know that with my current code it's obvious but I have no idea how to achieve this).
Here an example of what happens if you scroll down (What I don't want):

[image]

I want it to continue moving up but under the block of "new chat"

Does someone know how to achieve this? It can be in javascript or jQuery as well.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: can you show the code snippet plz, it would be easily solve able when understand the code.

Comment: If you want to set the first position then you have to change the index not the Y position. For changing the index position you have to use JS/JQUERY

Comment: @MuhammadNadeemArif I tried to duplicate my code the best I could. I added a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room for improvement but more or less does what you want I think.

https://jsfiddle.net/phaelax/efgLub1p/4/

```
        var offset = 0;
        
        
        $(function(){
                    
            $('#thing').on('click', '.singlechatContainer', function(e){
                if (!$('#thing').children('li.moving').length){
                    $('#thing').children('li').removeClass('selected');
                    $(e.target).addClass('moving selected');
                    xi = setInterval("moveItem()", 10);
                }
            });
        
        });
        
        
        function moveItem(t){
            
            var $m = $('#thing').children('li.moving');
            offset += 1;
            
            
            
            if ($m.not(':first-child').length){
                if (offset >= $m.outerHeight()){
                    $m.prev().before($m);
                    offset = 0;
                }
            }else{
                offset = 0;
                clearInterval(xi);
                $m.removeClass('moving');
            }
            
            $m.css('margin-top', '-'+offset+'px').css('margin-bottom', offset+'px');
            

        }
```

javascript

```
.singlechatContainer{padding:4px;color:#EEE;position:relative;}
.selected{background:#3399ff;border-radius:3px;color:white}
ul{list-style:none;background:#3a3a3a;font-family:arial}
ul li:hover{cursor:pointer}
.moving{z-index:1;}
```

css

```
<body>

    
    <div style="width:300px;">
        <ul id="thing">
            <li class="singlechatContainer ">Apples</li>
            <li class="singlechatContainer ">Bananas </li>
            <li class="singlechatContainer">Grapefruits</li>
            <li class="singlechatContainer ">Peaches</li>
            <li class="singlechatContainer ">Radishes</li>
            <li class="singlechatContainer ">Starfruit</li>
        </ul>   
    </div>

    
</body>
```

html

Comment: Awesome! Exact what I was looking for! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue where Hello2 moves on top of Hello1, you would need add `padding-top` in your `.nav` that is equal to height of a `.singlechatContainer`.

For the second issue, since, you're only translating to a fixed value of `calc(-20vw + 70px)`, it will stop. **Instead, you should use `top: 0;` to ensure that it goes all the way to the top regardless of the scroll position.** *You don't need `transform`.* **Also, you may need to add `position: relative` to your `.nav`.**

For both issues, I would revise my CSS to:

```
.nav {
    position: relative;
}

.nav.has-moved {
    padding-top: 40px; // <-- Adjust according to height of .singlechatContainer
}

.singlechatContainer {
    -moz-transition: all 5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 5s;
    -o-transition: all 5s;
    transition: all 5s;
}
.is-moved {
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0; // <-- Notice, we removed transform
}
```

It is assumed you would add `has-moved` class to your `.nav` when the chat is selected.

Comment: But hello2 will still have position absolute and will only be visually the first Item. I want it to become the first item in the list but using the effect as it move to the top.